# Equations with justifications in angle brackets in Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

How would I do something like this :

```
    f(x)
=      < Justification >
    x + y + a
=      < according to ... >
    abc
```

Which math environment should I use get this kind of equations? And how can I display 2 such blocks side by side?

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this (this saves space too).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{alignedat} {4}
    f(x) &= x + y + a & \qquad &  \text{(You say it)}\\
         &= abc       & \qquad &  \text{(According to me)}
  \end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `amsmath` is enough and the second `\qquad` isn't needed.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Well, I always use `mathtools` (habit) and use of `\qquad` is always subjective. Anyway, thanks for the comment.